# Develop android MAP with web server

Tags: android, google-maps, webserver

I have here a map that tracks my current location. Now i want my map to have pin for all nearby hospital and pharmacy. But i want to have also a web server that i can manage for marking hospitals/pharmacy. Those changes or added pinned/marked location from a web server can be updated in my android device. Anyway I am using Xampp as my localhost server.

Here's my android code for map. It's working already but there's still no pinned hospital location and pharmacy.

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.Menu;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class GoogleMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.map);

LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
.getMap();

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

map.clear();

MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();

mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

mp.title("my position");

map.addMarker(mp);

map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 16));

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: You're going to want to take a look into Google's Places API. I don't know much about it, but I can point you down the right path. Look into implementing Google Places API on your server and then you can return a JSON array of all of the locations of hospitals and pharmacies to the mobile devices. Here's a list of supported places types that you can look up. https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types

Comment: @drees is that possible that i can manage the markers of my android MAP by using a webserver?

Comment: Very possible. I'm not familiar with xxamp so I can't help you much past this point, but you can make an api call to the server with the phones location and have the server return a JSON string of all hospital's and pharmacy's latitudes and longitudes in the area. Then populate the map with that information

Comment: ok i get your point. but i really don't know how to start with it. i'm just a beginner for this thing. Any way tnx for answering me. Hope i can find some codes there.